# xcworkspace not correctly loading xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I was sent a project folder by someone because I was contracted to help work on it. The project runs and compiles with no problems on their end, but is having issues when I try to run it. When I open the workspace, the xcodeproj file is red, and none of the associated project files appear under it - the Pods project and all of the pod files appear correctly. The files are definitely there in the folder - I can open the xcodeproj and all of its files show correctly there. Looking at the file inspector, it looks like the Pods project file path is pointing to the correct location on my computer, but the main project file path points to the location on the computer of the person who sent it to me. If I click the folder icon next to this and change the file path to the correct location on my computer it's no longer red, but it still doesn't load properly and the rest of the project files still aren't there.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode can be a bit funny about things like this. After Correcting the path to the project, try closing and reopening XCode. Often that will fix issues like this.

Comment: I tried this several times, but as is more often than not the case, I tried it again now and it worked like a charm. Darn it Xcode. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following solution with shared steps

1. GoTo Project directory and delete Podfile.lock file
2. Open your project in terminal
3. Run command - (pod install)
4. pod install will install all the specified library in your project with available or define the version
5. Now click on the workspace and you are ready to go !!